# unir los objetos de dos arreglos distintos en javascript

Tags: javascript, objeto

Yo he hecho esta funcion pero no funciona :

```
function mergeData(users, attendances) {
for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j< attendances.length ; j++){
        if(users[i].email == attendances[j].email ){
         users[i].attendances = attendances[j].email;
        }
    }
}
return users;
```

Y lo que yo quiero es que al ingresar estos dos arreglos, el primer arreglo en el parametro users y el segundo arreglo en el parametro attendances  :

Primer arreglo :

```
[
  { name: 'Georg', email: 'georg@academlo.com' },
  { name: 'Andrea', email: 'andrea@gmail.com' }
]
```

Segundo arreglo:

```
    [
  { email: 'georg@academlo.com', attendance: true },
  { email: 'andrea@gmail.com', attendance: false }
]
```

Yo quiero obtener lo siguiente:

```
[
    { name: 'Georg', email: 'georg@academlo.com', attendance: true },
    { name: 'Andrea', email: 'andrea@gmail.com', attendance: false }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
 a = [
    { name: 'Georg', email: 'georg@academlo.com' },
    { name: 'Andrea', email: 'andrea@gmail.com' }
  ]

b = [
  { email: 'andrea@gmail.com', attendance: true },
  { email: 'georg@academlo.com' , attendance: false }
];

// copiamos el elemento
c = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)); 
// recorremos el elemto
for( x in a)
//recorremos el otro elemento
   for ( y in b)
   //verificamos que a en la posicion x sea igual a b en la posicion x
     if ( a[x].email == b[y].email )
         c[x]["attendance"]  = b[y].attendance
  console.log(c)
  console.log(a)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Por ultimo si en lugar de tener a  "a" y  "b" como variables fijas se necesitara ingresar esos valores al llamar una funcion yo escribi la funcion MergeData pero no funciona al momento de retornar el valor.

Comment: ```function mergeData(users, attendances) {
  for ( x in users)
    for( y in attendances)
      if(users[x].email == attendances[y].email )
          users[x]["attendance"] = b[y].attendance

 }
 return users;
 
 console.log(mergeData([
  { name: 'Georg', email: 'georg@academlo.com' },
  { name: 'Andrea', email: 'andrea@gmail.com' }
],
[
  { email: 'georg@academlo.com', attendance: true },
  { email: 'andrea@gmail.com', attendance: false }
]
));```

Comment: ahi te deje el codigo de mi funcion

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que esa "coia" (`c = a`) no hace nada... al final también estás modificando `a` (para que lo tengas en cuenta)